# Is providing tutorial URL allowed

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, third-party

Would you please tell if below is allowed:

1. When answer questions: Is it OK to provide third party site link in the bottom for user to click and see details of answer with implementation ?
2. How many third party site URL is allowed ?
3. Is anybody check provided URL is not spam and intimate user about it who has answer the questions ?

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs on the meta site. IIRC, the guideline is that answers should be complete without having to visit external sites. You can link to them, but your answer should not become 'wrong/invalid' if the external site stops working or is not accessible.

Comment: Here's an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921285/what-is-equal-with-trigger-in-javascript/22921531#22921531 I wrote an answer that has an external link, but instead of just leaving it at that, I included the answer from the link directly within my question. Note however that if the link you are providing is to another answer on stackoverflow.com, you should instead vote to close the question as a duplicate of that question *if it is a duplicate*.

Comment: Thanks Colin and Kevin.I have heard Google search treat third party link on forum site as spam not sure what is their algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. third party links are allowed, but only if they relate to the question. For example, if I have a question about C++ inheritance, and in an answer someone wants to reference the official documentation, then a third party link is appropriate.

However, irrelevant links in answers may be flagged as spam, deleted or edited away. If I post the same question as above, and someone posts an answer that has a link to Python documentation, it may be acceptable with a thorough explanation.

Of course, if you post a third party link to Prescription Drugs Now!, then your answer will be flagged as spam and it will be deleted. Your account will also suffer the repercussions of posting spam, which we take seriously here. Other users *will* notice the spam and you *will* be in hot water for it. You usually don't need to be familiar with the question to smell when something is spam.

Also, do not post link-only answers. Answers should be still useful even if links go dead or become removed. You can include as many third-party links as you wish, as long as they are appropriate.

Comment: Link-only answers are very much discouraged, though. A link should relate to the question *and* the gist of the link should be fleshed out in the answer, so the answer remains valid even if the link goes dead.

Comment: @Pëkka Thanks, I added that to the answer. I was thinking of referencing your handbags in here as spam, too :)